# How to change language of full android application based on users choice from a listview?

Tags: android, listview, locale

I am creating an android application. i want to have a screen that asks the user to select their preferred language. Here is my code for my listview.

```
public class LanguageSelect extends Activity {                          
int[] IMAGES = {R.drawable.english, R.drawable.french, R.drawable.spanish, R.drawable.german, R.drawable.swedish, R.drawable.russia};

String[] NAMES = {"English", "Français", "Español", "Deutsche", "svenska", "русский"};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_language_select);

    ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.Lang);

    CustomAdpater customadapter = new CustomAdpater();

    listView.setAdapter(customadapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if(i==0)
            {
                LangHelper.changeLocale(this.getResources(), "fr");
            }
        }
    });
}

class CustomAdpater extends BaseAdapter{
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return IMAGES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup)
    {
        view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_layout_lang,null);

        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView textViewLang=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewLang);

        imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES[i]);
        textViewLang.setText(NAMES[i]);

        return view;
    }
}}
```

I also have created several string.xml files for the languages i wish to use from a tutorial i found. see image below

[strings.xml image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXjFQ.png)

I also created a LangHelper class. see below

```
public class LangHelper {

public static void changeLocale(Resources res, String locale)
{
    Configuration config;
    config = new Configuration(res.getConfiguration());

    switch (locale) {
        case "es":
            config.locale = new Locale("es");
            break;
        case "fr":
            config.locale = new Locale("fr");
            break;
        default:
            config.locale = new Locale("en");
    }
    res.updateConfiguration(config, res.getDisplayMetrics());
}}
```

My issue now is connecting the LangHelper class to the Listview, so that when the user selects their desired language from the list the following pages i.e. the full application is now translated into that language that the user has selected

Comment: Why did you delete [your question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49513788/csv-conversion-to-json-for-android-application-cascading-menu)? I am not sure it was on-topic (probably too broad) but presumably you still need an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes your code is correct and if you want without refreshing the application

then In Your **Application** class you need to call this in `onCreate()` method

```
String languageSelected = "en";//selected language
Locale myLocale = new Locale(languageSelected);
Resources res = getResources();
DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
conf.locale = myLocale;
res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
getActivity().onConfigurationChanged(conf);//Call this method
```

You need to perform this particular language to be selected on Application class.

Comment: I have placed this code into my LanguageSelect.class. is that correct? i am also getting error on "getActivity()" saying "Cannot resolve method"... sorry for my lack of knowledge, i am not very good at coding.

Comment: Remove getActivity().

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        TextView textViewLang=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textViewLang);
        String lang = textViewLang.getText():
        LangHelper.changeLocale(this.getResources(), lang);
    }
});
```